# LottieAnimation not running inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-animation, lottie

I have a star animation for giving rating and I created three of such LottieAnimationViews inside my fragment for the purpose of reuse-ability. The LottieAnimation doesn't even start when I run it from inside the `onCreate()` method of my Fragment (I am using support Fragments). The exact same code runs the animation if it is inside an `Activity` instead of a fragment. Here's my code...

```
    mLottieStarView1 = findViewById(R.id.rating_lottie_star_1);  //LottieView
    starLayout1 = findViewById(R.id.rating_star_layout_1); //Enclosing LinearLayout
    mValueAnimator1 = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 1f).setDuration(1500);

    //Create animation update methods
    mValueAnimator1.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {  //Star 1
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            mLottieStarView1.setProgress((Float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue());
        }
    });

    //Set listener on enclosing layout to run animation on touch
    starLayout1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mLottieStarView2.setProgress(0f);
            mLottieStarView3.setProgress(0f);
            mValueAnimator1.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Same here using AndroidX, FragmentActivity and ViewPager2

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set the image View to `isClickable = true`
and `isFocusable = true` in xml.

Start the lottie animation using the `lottieView.playAnimation();` method and for the unclick try this

```
if(lottieTest.getFrame() == lottieTest.getMaxFrame()) {
   lottieTest.setFrame(1);
}
```